How to save Stream data from external GET request in .NET
I am currently in my .NET (c#) backend, making a GET call to an external URL which returns a responseType: 'stream'.  In this case it is streaming back data which should be a valid .PDF file once complete.  Calling this external API from Postman works fine and displays the pdf, but my code doesnt seem to be getting all of the streamed data, causing an invalid file.
Here is my function:
private async Task<string?> ReadFileData(string url)
{
    string fileData = null;

        using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            fileData += await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        return fileData;
    }

Just one of the things I've tried, but I dont seem to be streaming the entire dataset, although I am getting the first 15 or so lines of what should be a multiple hundreds of lines (of raw text) pdf file, I did quite a bit of research but didn't seem to find anything.  I'm sure I'm missing something dumb regarding the data streaming, if anyone has any incite that'd be great

Try fileData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); instead of +=

Do you know what kind of response it's returning  or type of data have you seen in postman?


Just one of the things I've tried, but I dont seem to be streaming the
entire dataset, although I am getting the first 15 or so lines of what
should be a multiple hundreds of lines (of raw text) pdf file, I did
quite a bit of research but didn't seem to find anything.

According to your scenario and description along with the shared code snippet, I have tried to troubleshoot your issue.
Based on my test, the problem in your code lies in the way you are handling the response content. You are trying to read the content as a string, which is not suitable for binary data like a PDF file. Instead, you need to handle the stream properly.
In order to fix that,  read the stream data using ReadAsStreamAsync into a MemoryStream and then convert it to a byte array, which you can then process or save as needed. Here’s how you can call ReadFileDataAsync method and save the data to a file if required:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FileAccessController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public FileAccessController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    }

    [HttpGet("download-file")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            //Passing the url to the file content reading method
            byte[] fileData = await ReadFileDataAsync(url);

            // I am Returning the file as a FileResult
            return File(fileData, "application/pdf", "downloaded-file.pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private async Task<byte[]> ReadFileDataAsync(string url)
    {
        using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:





Note: Following above way, you have the complete PDF data in fileData which you can use as needed. If you don’t need to save it to a file, you can use the fileData byte array directly in your application. Please refer to this official document if you need any additional assistance.

I wanna say this is a great answer, although I still have some data loss when the byte[] is converted to a string for some reason.  If I write out via WriteAllBytes(), it has a valid good PDF file, but if I convert to a string, it's busted. Maybe I'm missing some information about the string conversion.  Maybe the default Encoding is wrong?

Hi thanks for your response, when dealing with binary files like PDFs, it's important to remember that these files should not be treated as text. Converting binary data to a string and back can cause data loss due to encoding issues. Instead, you should handle them as binary data throughout the process. If you need to manipulate a binary file such as a PDF, avoid converting it to a string.
